# Ranking occurrences in field using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

I have a field `C_CODE` and I would like to count occurences of values in that field that will start with zero in front of the one digit numbers:Ex: 01,02 and normally for two digit numbers Ex:..09,10,11,etc

Wanted output:

```
C_CODE RANK  C_CODE_FINAL                        #Info#
17      01       1701      # RANK counts how many times each value in C_CODE exists
15      01       1501      # C_CODE_FINAL is a concatenation of the other fields
23      01       2301
29      01       2901
15      02       1502
19      01       1901
17      02       1702
15      03       1503
37      01       3701
```

and then concat the fields to `C_CODE_FINAL` .

Tried:

```
fc = path to shp
field = "C_CODE"

#Create dictionary to store unique values
count_values = {}
arcpy.AddField_management (fc, 'rank', 'LONG')
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor (fc, field) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if not row[0] in count_values.keys():
            count_values[row[0]] = 1
        else:
            count_values[row[0]] += 1
```

It returns a rank column filled with zeros although there are many values that exist multiple times. Also they have to start with 01 for values that appear for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue is that you have the new field 'rank' defined as a long.  That is fine, but you can't directly control the format of the data; you'll have to format the display.  If you must store it with a leading zero, make it a text field.  The same could be true of C_CODE_FINAL.

Unless I am misunderstanding the requirement, it should be easier to use an UpdateCursor and update the values as you move through the cursor.

The following is partial code (add code to create fields as needed) and untested:

```
fields = ["C_CODE", 'RANK', 'C_CODE_FINAL']

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor (fc, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if not row[0] in count_values.keys():
            count_values[row[0]] = 1
        else:
            count_values[row[0]] += 1
        row[1] = count_values[row[0]]
        row[2] = str(row[0]) + str(row[1]).zfill(2)
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```